# How to find missing files?

Tags: linux, r

I have several files (with the same dim) in a folder called `data` for certain dates:

```
 file2011001.bin   named like this "fileyearday"
 file2011009.bin
 file2011020.bin
      .
      .
 file2011322.bin
```

certin dates(files) are missing. What I need is just loop through these files

```
if file2011001.bin exist  ok, if not copy any file in the directory and name it file2011001.bin    
if file2011002.bin exist  ok, if not copy any file in the directory and name it file2011002.bin   and so on untill file2011365.bin
```

I can list them in `R`:

```
dir<- list.files("/data/", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
```

I wonder if it is possible thru R or any other language!

Comment: Are you looking for the loop to return a message or actually create the missing files?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what you'd expect:

```
AllFiles = paste0("file", 2010:2015, 0:364, ".bin")

for(file in AllFiles)
{
    if(file.exists(file))
    {
       ## do something
    }
}
```